# Pygame Sprite not updating immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pygame

EDIT: I have fixed it, there should be a self infront of the return for invader_position_x

I am making a space invaders game. However I have encountered strange behavior.

When I press the right key on my keyboard, the sprite does not move but after holding it down for a few seconds, it jumps to the right boundary.

The space invader game is using classes and this is the main class:

```
# IMPORTS
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import invader

pygame.init()
###################
#IMAGE SIZE AND FPS
width = 800
height = 600
fps = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
#################

#OTHER VARIABLES
pygame.display.set_caption('space invaders!')
white = (225,225,225)# The colour white
invader_sprite = pygame.image.load("cross.png")
invader_lenght = 40
invader_position_x = 400
invader_position_y = 560
right_boundary = width- invader_lenght

keypress = ""
my_invader = invader.Invader(invader_position_x,right_boundary,keypress)# Initialising invader

while True: # main game loop
    DISPLAY.fill(white)
    DISPLAY.blit(invader_sprite,(invader_position_x,invader_position_y))
    keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    invader_position_x=my_invader.invader_move(keypress,right_boundary,invader_position_x)
    print(invader_position_x)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(fps)
```

This is my invader class in a seperate file:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

class Invader():

    def __init__(self,invader_position_x,right_boundary,keypress):

        self.invader_position_x= invader_position_x        
        self.right_boundary=right_boundary
        self.keypress= keypress

    def invader_move(self,keypress,right_boundary,invader_position_x):
        if self.invader_position_x> right_boundary:#Right boundary
            invader_position_x=right_boundary-5
        if self.invader_position_x<0:
            invader_position_x= 5

        if keypress[K_RIGHT]:# right
            self.invader_position_x = self.invader_position_x+ 5

        elif keypress[K_LEFT]:# left
            self.invader_position_x =self.invader_position_x- 5

        return invader_position_x
```

So what is the solution to fixing this weird behaviour?

Comment: I think there's a mixup between `invader_position_x` and `self.invader_position_x`

Comment: I have worked it out. the return did not have self infront! Thanks very much!

Comment: if you have class `Invader` then you should keep its position, length and sprite inside this class.

Comment: you uses two variables to keep position - global `invader_position_x` and `self.invader_position_x`. You should have only one `self.invader_position_x` or better short `self.x` or even better use `pygame.Rect()`  to keep size and position because `pygame.Rect()` has many usefull methods ie. for checking collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is that you have two variables to keep position . But I didn't check this - I changed code to make it better organized and problem disappeared.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30

WHITE = (225, 225, 225)

# --- classes ---

class Invader():

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.image = pygame.image.load("cross.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self, screen_rect, keypress):#EDIT Replaced screen with screem_rect

        if keypress[pygame.K_RIGHT]:  # right
            self.rect.x += 15

        elif keypress[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left
            self.rect.x -= 15

        if self.rect.right > screen_rect.right: # right boundary
            self.rect.right = screen_rect.right

        if self.rect.left < screen_rect.left:
            self.rect.left = screen_rect.left

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption('space invaders!')

# - objects -

my_invader = Invader(400, 560)

# - mainloop -

fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True: # main game loop

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # - updates -

    my_invader.update(screen_rect, keypress)

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    my_invader.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -

    fps_clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and I will try this later. May I ask what the rect does?

Comment: [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) keeps size and position, it has `x`, `y`. `width`, `height` but also `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, `center`, etc. (you cna use `center` to center object on screen or text on button) and it has method to check collisions - `colliderect` (with other rect), `collidepoint` (with point , ie. mouse position to make clickable button), etc.